# libdgx vector3 conversion wrong

Tags: android, libgdx

Evening Everyone,

I am attempting to get familiar with libdgx and android by going thru the tutorial [Here](http://www.todroid.com/game-programming-using-android-studio-and-gdx-lib-part-ii/).  All seems good except for grabbing the screen coordinates as they get skewed in a Vector3 conversion.

So x input of 101 gets converted to -796, y input of 968 converted to -429 (touching the upper left corner of the screen, same results from emulator as from my phone). When clicking the bottom right corner, the animation fires in the middle of the screen.

It all seems pretty basic so not really sure what I am setting incorrectly to get a skewed conversion.  Any help is appreciated!

camera creation:

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth * .5f, camera.viewportHeight * .5f, 0f);
```

Grabbing touch coord:

```
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    touchCoordinateX = screenX;
    touchCoordinateY = screenY;
    stateTime = 0;
    explosionHappening = true;
    return true;
}
```

Render loop:

```
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    batch.begin();

    if (!explosionAnimation.isAnimationFinished(stateTime) && explosionHappening) {
        Vector3 touchPoint = new Vector3();
        touchPoint.set(touchCoordinateX,touchCoordinateY,0);
        TextureRegion currentFrame = explosionAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, false);  // #16
        camera.unproject(touchPoint);
        batch.draw(currentFrame, touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y);
    }
            //  batch.draw(img, 0, 0);
    batch.end();
    if (explosionAnimation.isAnimationFinished(stateTime)){explosionHappening = false;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to set camera projection matrix to your SpriteBatch. Just add

```
batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
```

before

```
batch.begin();
```

Comment: Yerp, adding that fixed it!  Many thanks.  Is there a good source besides the adhoc tutorials that outline where, why and how?  The listing of each item describes what it does, but not necessarily how they can be put together.

Comment: You should mark my answer as accepted if it fixed it. For tutorial see official libGDX wiki: [https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki)